# Preserving whitespace with XmlProvider.Load

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm using the FSharp.Data library, how can I specify the following option:

```
LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace
```

with the Load method? I've tried passing it in but the compiler complains there's no such overload.

```
type Detailed = XmlProvider<"./samples/sample.xml">
let test = Detailed.Load(fi, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)
```

fi is just a file stream object.

Comment: How did your try to pass it in? Give code samples, describe exactly what happens, describe exactly what effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I've updated my question

Comment: And I would like to be able to just specify an existing `XDocument` in `Load`...

Comment: Might Detailed.Parse be of more use?